# resources not found exception gridadapter gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I am working on the app which has gridview in its main activity it is running fine on my device (API 28) but on lower version devices it crashes idk the reason. Can anyone help me. Let me mention Compile and target SDK is 27 and minSdk is 21.

logcat shows error(Resource Not found exception) on this line imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
Here is the code

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    private final String[] values;
    private final int [] images;
    View view;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public GridAdapter(Context context, String[] values, int[] images)
    {
        this.context=context;
        this.values=values;
        this.images=images;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return values.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(convertView == null){
            view = new View (context);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, null);
            ImageView imageView =(ImageView)view.findViewById (R.id.iv1);
            TextView textView=(TextView)view.findViewById (R.id.tv1);
            imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
            textView.setText (values[position]);
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

This is the logcat

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f08007e
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2596)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:328)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
        at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:85)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:93)
        at com.faisalnazir.computerapplications.GridAdapter.getView(GridAdapter.java:49)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:3061)
        at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1463)
        at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:366)
        at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:307)
        at android.widget.GridView.fillFromTop(GridView.java:442)
        at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1291)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2848)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:2520)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1769)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
        at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:132)
        at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
        at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:894)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3172)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
        at android.view.V
```

Comment: Make sure your images are in **drawable** folder and not **drawable-xxx* where xxx can be v21 etc.

Comment: Initially some of them were in drawable v24 folder then I moved all of them in drawable folder ... But it didn't work

Comment: No I am not using xm/vector drawables

Comment: where is the images array loaded from?

Comment: From main activity in which gridview is placed

Comment: I meant where do these ids come from, are these loaded from xml file?